# High performance asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net

Which things i should take care to develop high performance asp.net application.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: What is the application going to do?  There is a massive difference between making a simple CRUD application with a handful of DB tables, and an e-commerce, real-time business intelligence application capable of handling millions of transactions a second.

Comment: It's a general question.  Obviously he can only expect general answers.  That's perfectly legitimate as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Its a real time application with lots of users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://blog.whiletrue.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-performance/ and http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/17/the-performances-implications-of-the-expression-tree-based-actionlink-helper.aspx.
I'm working too on a blog post about performances. Up to now just realized a [simple bench tool](http://dotnetmarche.org/blogs/andreabalducci/archive/2009/04/24/introducing-abanalyzer-an-apache-bench-runner-and-analyzer.aspx) using apache bench to compare client side rendering and server rendering using asp.net mvc and jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Look at caching opportunities.  Make sure it isn't "chatty."

Comment: viewstate in aspnet.mvc? ... sounds new

Comment: Trigger happy. To clarify. MVC does not have ViewState.

Comment: @Diago - You'd be surprised what you can hack together :)  I read 70% of the title, next time I will read at least 80% so I see the "M" and then I might see the "VC....."